# how to get the file with the lowest number of hardlink?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to get the file with the lowest number of hardlink but I don't Know why but something went wrong.I post below my code.Thanks to all.
(Ps. sorry for my english)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

struct stat s;
nlink_t cont=10000;
char name[1000];

       DIR* d;
       d=opendir("/home/user/Desktop/");
       struct dirent* d2;
       while((d2=readdir(d))!=NULL){
           lstat(d2->d_name,&s);
            if(S_ISREG(s.st_mode)){
           if(cont < s.st_nlink){
               cont=s.st_nlink;
               strcpy(name,d2->d_name);
                }
              }
            }

printf("\nFile:%s\n",name);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The condition `cont < s.st_nlink` seems inverted.

Comment: Thank you,now my code runs.The error was trivial.I did not notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d2->d_name` is just the name of the directory but `lstat` requires a path, either relative or absolute. So unless your current working dir is /home/user/Desktop/, `lstat` would fail. You need to construct the path and you should always check the return code from function calls like `lstat`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `cont < s.st_nlink` is inverted, `<` should be `>`.

(That being said, the premise of finding "the" file with *lowest* number of hardlinks is a bit odd to me, it is very likely that any real system would have multiple files with 1 link.)